# Installing Aeson package using Stack

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, haskell-stack

To use Json, I want to install the Aeson package.

In the `package.yaml` file I added `- aeson`to the `dependencies:` section, and I got a whole load of errors, which I cannot find online like: "But this GHC boot package has been pruned".

I tried to understand the errors, but I don't understand any of them. For example for the first one: If I do `stack ls dependencies` I get `text 1.2.4.0`, which meets the matches, so why doesn't it work?

Is there a way to let Stack install things for me instead of having to edit the yaml file and then running into issues? (`stack install` doesnt seem to do anything)

The full error:

```
PS D:\Documents\Programming\Unity\Poging8_(catan)\HaskellServer> stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for aeson-1.4.7.1:
    text must match >=1.2.3.0 && <1.3, but this GHC boot package has been pruned (issue #4510); you need to add the
         package explicitly to extra-deps  (latest matching version is 1.2.4.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> aeson-1.4.7.1

In the dependencies for attoparsec-0.13.2.4:
    text must match >=1.1.1.3, but this GHC boot package has been pruned (issue #4510); you need to add the package
         explicitly to extra-deps  (latest matching version is 1.2.4.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> attoparsec-0.13.2.4

In the dependencies for ghc-boot-th-8.6.5:
    base-4.13.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.7 && <4.13  (latest matching version is 4.12.0.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> ghc-boot-th-8.6.5

In the dependencies for hashable-1.3.0.0:
    text must match >=0.12 && <1.3, but this GHC boot package has been pruned (issue #4510); you need to add the package
         explicitly to extra-deps  (latest matching version is 1.2.4.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> hashable-1.3.0.0

In the dependencies for scientific-0.3.6.2:
    text must match >=0.8, but this GHC boot package has been pruned (issue #4510); you need to add the package
         explicitly to extra-deps  (latest matching version is 1.2.4.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> scientific-0.3.6.2

In the dependencies for template-haskell-2.14.0.0:
    base-4.13.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.9 && <4.13  (latest matching version is 4.12.0.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> template-haskell-2.14.0.0

In the dependencies for time-1.8.0.4:
    base-4.13.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.7 && <4.13  (latest matching version is 4.12.0.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> time-1.8.0.4

In the dependencies for uuid-types-1.0.3:
    text must match >=1 && <1.3, but this GHC boot package has been pruned (issue #4510); you need to add the package
         explicitly to extra-deps  (latest matching version is 1.2.4.0)
needed due to HaskellCatanServer-0.1.0.0 -> uuid-types-1.0.3

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Build requires unattainable version of base. Since base is a part of GHC, you most likely need to use a different
    GHC version with the matching base.

Plan construction failed.
```

Additional information:

In `package.yaml` I have dependencies:

```
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- network
- bytestring
- aeson
```

I have NOT manually edited `stack.yaml`, and I have resolver lts-16.3 and extra-deps:

```
- ghc-8.6.5@sha256:3591225289bdf8cf8f62b10f2aebc9ea3e25a15294545a5312a419e0317784f9,13976
- ghc-boot-8.6.5@sha256:8b608d2f36aad99a37a7d1b70319d43195128de6485b15fa7d4638b2942ce2a2,1772
- ghc-boot-th-8.6.5@sha256:c120f0d15944e770e2b698f5139f0003a86f9e25e5d1a7c6631e442129232748,1075
- ghci-8.6.5@sha256:886e52e6ab43b0de39fd5d92d8d1a5d7fac04c0f145c62b39baae04476208bd9,2126
- template-haskell-2.14.0.0@sha256:e3747ae9e2aeec160196706dd470b5fc4175678ec4136bcec9124534f67d83bc,1724
- time-1.8.0.4@sha256:3f6eddf238b828eb4f82683acce1c3afe64784f0d20114239b738c123316c85c,5494
```

`stack ls dependencies`

```
Win32 2.6.1.0
aeson 1.4.7.1
array 0.5.4.0
attoparsec 0.13.2.4
base 4.13.0.0
base-compat 0.11.1
base-compat-batteries 0.11.1
base-orphans 0.8.2
binary 0.8.7.0
bytestring 0.10.10.0
containers 0.6.2.1
deepseq 1.4.4.0
dlist 0.8.0.8
filepath 1.4.2.1
ghc-boot-th 8.6.5
ghc-prim 0.5.3
hashable 1.3.0.0
integer-gmp 1.0.2.0
integer-logarithms 1.0.3
network 3.1.1.1
pretty 1.1.3.6
primitive 0.7.0.1
random 1.1
rts 1.0
scientific 0.3.6.2
tagged 0.8.6
template-haskell 2.14.0.0
text 1.2.4.0
th-abstraction 0.3.2.0
time 1.8.0.4
time-compat 1.9.3
transformers 0.5.6.2
unordered-containers 0.2.10.0
uuid-types 1.0.3
vector 0.12.1.2
```

Comment: Try removing all these extra deps.

Comment: @arrowd Well that was simple. If you know why this helped, maybe you can write up an answer? It now seems like magic, since I didn't edit that file in the first place.

Comment: And this is exactly why I can't write an answer. Generally, the `stack.yaml` is very minimal file, so I also have no idea where all these constrains came from. As rule of thumb, just try to keep all the extra stuff away from `stack.yaml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your problem is a miss match between `lts` and `extra-deps` versions. As @arrowd commented, the solution is to remove `extra-deps` section... Let me explain the reason in detail:

- Each `lts` (a.k.a `snapshot`) has an associated ghc version. For [lts-16.3](https://www.stackage.org/lts-16.3) such a version is `ghc-8.8.3` as you can check in the linked docs.
- when you write a dependency in `package.yaml`, `stack` will use the version defined in the selected `lts`, and it'll be downloaded form `stackage` server. For example, in the linked docs, you can search for `aeson` package. The version used in `lts-16.3` is `aeson-1.4.7.1`
- All packages version in a `lts` are guaranteed to work well together without dependency problems. (I think there are a few exceptions documented in the stack web, due to system packages but I'm not so sure)
- The problem comes with `extra-deps`. Which are downloaded directly from `hackage` server with no guarantees of dependency compatibility. In your case, one extra dep was `ghc-8.6.5`. Obviously, there is a dependency problem between the compiler version defined in the snapshot: `ghc-8.8.3` and the version you want as an extra-dep `ghc-8.6.5`

Hope it clarifies some `stack` terminology.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Maybe you can add the solution @arrowd mentioned in his comment as well so this answer is an explanation for the solution, as well as the solution itself.