# transformers-0.5.6.2 from stack configuration does not match >=0.3 && ==0.2.*

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm trying to include quickcheck-instances package for testing. Here is how my dependencies field in package.yaml looks like:

```
dependencies:
- blackjack
- quickcheck-instances >= 0.3.25 && < 0.4
- QuickCheck >= 2.14.2 && < 2.15
```

Here is how my extra-deps field in stack.yaml looks like:

```
extra-deps:
- quickcheck-instances-0.3.25.2@sha256:083b84b91fccb3bbf22cd906f5bc731c8e6ee96c7554e892985452f2d61d4ad3,4484
- hashable-1.3.3.0@sha256:7f3b67151162a1dfe8472dc30430af98ed5470801d3f4b6c9b8d7a7443c920d4,4068
- unordered-containers-0.2.14.0@sha256:2fe789f78246b7c7ec10d7b85c72d898a9f72fdda5b60d581e839d21016bc628,4992
- QuickCheck-2.14.2@sha256:4ce29211223d5e6620ebceba34a3ca9ccf1c10c0cf387d48aea45599222ee5aa,7736
- case-insensitive-1.2.1.0@sha256:9dfd3171fc7698cf8d931727d3af3a7b389135b583e46b5adac1f9d2026fff61,2244
- data-fix-0.3.2@sha256:ca5ee8d5e15d08e65e9af74004cd663391706c0a62b7d1c6d0023e4c34cd0038,1659
- integer-logarithms-1.0.3.1@sha256:888fb6c4fbd79ed2e8f8b94b61bccac25f7fab2b13b32b496e86828bc60b17cf,3184
- old-time-1.1.0.3@sha256:c91fbb3ee73d20ccd015842b30f1f29a304893ebe0ae3128b7bbc13d5bb0d4c8,1328
- scientific-0.3.7.0@sha256:0f188a7b92780d81a2e3cf1195a3a24cfe3e7c43d0e9e0f2101a465803d68076,4773
- splitmix-0.1.0.3@sha256:fc3aae74c467f4b608050bef53aec17904a618731df9407e655d8f3bf8c32d5c,6049
- strict-0.4.0.1@sha256:50187e750751a258efea12ef2979e16a014a953c15bf4c2fca2f1168a44a5a12,4156
- tagged-0.8.6.1@sha256:29c67d98a4404607f024750ab9c7210dadcbbef4e1944c48c52902f2071b2662,2874
- these-1.1.1.1@sha256:bdc0a3015b2e5cdf016e402937d71856ae5fe4e9e9a0d4823cc94a214c55a39b,2732
- time-compat-1.9.6.1@sha256:cddf1a7654ccc3564d2197e6bf0064254abf792c591a9fa0eaa16e6039036152,4997
- uuid-types-1.0.5@sha256:5031383749d57cb95877d7e56f0300be66652b6e57f5ba6681dcc6e4f78d046d,2541
- vector-0.12.3.0@sha256:0ae2c1ba86f0077910be242ec6802cc3d7725fe7b2bea6987201aa3737b239b5,7953
- assoc-1.0.2@sha256:a824e4f615469a27ad949dbf4907ba258bd6b459deebec00524c7bcb3f65cc9f,1205
- base-orphans-0.8.5@sha256:b01baac1b88cc80e70214c064ec8c174718c19400232588bff591f5a9c49a750,3177
- old-locale-1.0.0.7@sha256:fa998be2c7e00cd26a6e9075bea790caaf3932caa3e9497ad69bc20380dd6911,1071
- primitive-0.7.2.0@sha256:d7c3635e83ae160129cdfe2be4092ab6389199d73a2c29adf904124dbcfe6100,2660
- random-1.2.0@sha256:195506fedaa7c31c1fa2a747e9b49b4a5d1f0b09dd8f1291f23a771656faeec3,6097
- bifunctors-5.5.11@sha256:cc425ee85aae56dba1123baf6fb3fa7abcd90782f26bb904eef14c7332ee85f6,3919
- comonad-5.0.8@sha256:1f1aabd73ec7f80f20cf078a748a60cd48d8e57277802fdf6a9ab3601a9b8f7e,3631
- th-abstraction-0.4.3.0@sha256:db4b3b69398acd8a7c5c8cc8a962da55d65d05d44d5039b51bd3cb5fb3d8400f,2148
- distributive-0.6.2.1@sha256:0f99f5541cca04acf89b64432b03422b6408e830a8dff30e6c4334ef1a48680c,2996
- indexed-traversable-0.1.1@sha256:e4602357513aa3b146546227732e6e5698392f4324ab690e109cc05676ba3b4f,2491
- transformers-compat-0.6.6@sha256:510709db2b12d1510d70de824ee544ca0a9e6f27aa7e299218cbacc0750b4a5e,5560
- transformers-0.5.6.2@sha256:6c959d14430f4deffb99579ba019de07c3d852a2122b6f449344386c7d75ff1d,3172
```

This is the error I got:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for transformers-compat-0.6.6:
    transformers-0.5.6.2 from stack configuration does not match >=0.3 && ==0.2.* 
needed due to blackjack-0.1.0.0 -> transformers-compat-0.6.6

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' in /home/xwtek/.stack/config.yaml to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.


Plan construction failed.
```

Of course after setting the allow-newer into true, it works, but I don't want to mess with that setting, because I fear that something like that would make things break later. Any better solution?

Comment: Which snapshot are you using? It seems weird so many `extra-deps`

Comment: @lsmor Well, quickcheck-instances is a large library, but isn't snapshot usually given next to each extra deps?

Comment: The stackage snapshot is define in `stack.yaml` with name `resolver` or `snapshot`. extra-deps is use for libraries not present in the stackage snapshot. No offense, but are you familiar with `stack`? I think you are missing some details. I've answered before something similar, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62792161/9271266. Feel free to ask what ever ;)

Comment: @Ismor I'm not very familiar, I'm just learning. For the resolver, I used nightly-2021-08-28 and ghc-9.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, you are missing how `stack` works. You should read the stack user guide, but let me explain briefly. `stack` uses two files to work:

- `stack.yaml`: It defines from *where* stack should download packages. By default `Stackage`. Optionally, git repos, hackage or local libraries.
- `package.yaml`: It defines *which* libraries you'll be using along with *how* to build your executable. Dependencies, compiler flags, test, etc...

In general the only thing you need to touch from `stack.yaml` is the resolver, and then use `package.yaml` to list your dependencies. So, How does `stack.yaml` is used?

You should have a line like this

```
resolver:
  url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/18/6.yaml
```

This specifies the set of packages you gonna use, called: resolver or snapshot. All libraries version within an snapshot are guaranteed to build togheter with no dependency hell. In the example above the resolver is set to `lts-18.6`. So, If you visit  [stackage](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.6) page for that snapshot you'll see all suported libraries and the compiler version: `ghc-8.10.4`

So let say I want to add `QuickCheck` to my dependencies. In my `package.yaml` I would list it down the library dependencies label

```
library:
  dependencies:
    - QuickCheck
```

The version of `QuickCheck` is determine by the selected resolver (`18.6`) which in this case is `QuickCheck-2.14.2` as you can check in the stackage web. Of course, it is a good practise to specify the actual version in `package.yaml`

```
library:
  dependencies:
    - QuickCheck-2.14.2
```

But it is not necessary, since the resolver already sets the version from you. If you need another version of the package, then you **have** to add it to `extra-deps`, indicating stack that you want packages from `lts-18.6` *and* a different package listed in `extra-deps`

The `stack` documentation is fairly good, so you should read it more carefully.

Comment: Did you had to respond like that "Clearly, you are missing how stack works. Let me explain briefly" it's rude and a bit egocentric... There is a respectful way to answer questions

Comment: @Adina does it sound rude? I didn't mean it, actually the answer comes after polite conversation in the comment section. The problem is that OP doesn't know how `stack` works, and based on the `extra-deps` field, it hasn't read the documentation either (not trying to blame OP). So, it is good to point out that OP is wrong about how `stack` works.

Comment: @Ismor ow ok my bad I didn't had the context before hand, I thought it was your first answer